# Google map GET error?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have installed Google map in my site and when my page load I get the error.

> GET
>   xdc._uqt0ll&token=129509">http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite_here.ext%2F&callback=*xdc*._uqt0ll&token=129509
>   403 (Forbidden)

AuthenticationService.Authenticate

Is there anyone who know what that's mean or how can I solve it ?

Comment: Note. I using Google Maps API V3

Comment: Look closely at the request. `xdc._uqt0ll&token=129509">` probably shouldn't be a part of it

Comment: Look closely at the request. It's not a proper URL, there's a HTML fragment in it - the URL should start with `http://`. You probably have an error somewhere in your source code